Time and if clauses
In English we have time and if clauses.

Provided you did it I will pay you

Once you did it I will pay you


Both are non-standard versions. I think one works ans makes sense because it is if  clause and 2 is just wrong because it is time clause and we need "once you do" to make the sentence correct, right?

#2 is a totally unacceptable / meaningless mishmash of verb tenses. #1 is "valid", but may not mean what you think it does. It means the speaker doesn't know whether the addressee did it or not (in the past - it can't refer to something the addressee might do in future). Speaker is saying that if it can be proved that addressee did do it, speaker will pay him. But even if addressee does it in the future, speaker might refuse to pay on the grounds that it was done too late.

(There's nothing "non-standard" about #1, and it's misleading to say #2 is non-standard - it's non-existent, since no native speaker would ever say it.)

I also question the link you are trying to make between "time and if clauses" (whatever you mean by that). Once you do it I will pay you is correct. If you do it I will pay you is also correct (but means something different). Your main mistake is using the wrong tense in the first place.


1: Provided you did it I will pay you
If you have already done it, I will pay you
(If you haven't already done it, even if you do it now I might not pay)


2: Once you did it I will pay you
(just nonsense)
2a: Once you do it I will pay you
normal English: I'll pay after you do it (which you haven't done yet)


Number 2 could also be expressed as Once you have done it I will pay you.

@FumbleFingers. So my understanding that it only works with if clauses is correct?

@Dary: I don't know what you mean. Perhaps you're not understanding how we use once to mean after in such contexts. Switching to if rather than provided, your first example (If you did it I will pay) is "unusual, unlikely", but perfectly valid. But I suspect the meaning you thought it had is what we would express by If you do it I will pay (addressee hasn't done it yet; he's being told he will be paid if he does it).
